# Jenkins build ignore tests

Tags: java, gradle, allure

I am executing TestNG test with Jenkins build and Allure plugin. My problem is that if I am executing them from IDEA all test results are displayed.

If I am using same configuration from Jenkins some tests are missing.

XML Suite file

```
<suite name="All in one" verbose="1"  thread-count="2" parallel="methods" >
<test name="Chrome:MainPage">
    <parameter name="browser"  value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="mainPage.MainPageTest" />
        <class name="patients.PatientsPageTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Firefox:MainPage">
    <parameter name="browser"  value="firefox"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="mainPage.MainPageTest" />
        <class name="patients.PatientsPageTest"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Result from Allure when directly "called" on results is good.

Allure plugin from Jenkins ignores some tests , and i have no idea why.

Comment: Did you double-checked the configuration of Allure plugin in TestNG. May be the test-output folder path needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution after 2 days , i am not sure which of them worked , but maybe someone will run into same issue someday...

- Check Jenkins version of Allure plugin
- Check Gradle version of Allure plugin
- Check TestNG for validity i missed this

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  ```